# Flutter unit test expect null vs. isNull

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, null

Is there a meaningful advantage of `isNull` compared to `null` in tests?

```
final String? str = null;
expect(str, null);
expect(str, isNull);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is typically no major benefit to utilising one over the other as both `null` and `isNull`.

- In tests, one may assert that a value is `null` by using the `null` keyword, a language feature in Dart that represents a null value. Like `expect(str, null)` declares that str's value is null.
- On the other hand, the `isNull` matcher in Flutter's `test` package verifies if a value is `null`. Like `expect(str, isNull)` declares that str's value is null.

---

In summary you can use whichever method you like in the majority of circumstances. But, it could be more logical to use `isNull` to check for `null` values if you're also using other matchers from the `test` package, such as `equals` or `isTrue`.